# Getting checkbox field editable in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am filling gridview from sql server store procedure. My aim is to make a checkbox field editable in gridview, i mean that when gridview display a record than Checkbox field (IsComplaint) should be editable in every row and shoud be reflected in database.

```
protected void btnSearchByDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
        DataTable dt = ManageQueueBizz.GetSmsComplaintsByDate(fromDate, toDate);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
            //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {

            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.DataBind();
            int totalcolums = GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = totalcolums;
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found";
            GridViewSmsComplaints.Visible = true;
            //gridViewComplaintsBySubject.Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

.aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewComplaintsByDate" AllowPaging="true"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid"  Width="408px" OnPageIndexChanging="gridViewComplaintsByDate_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridViewComplaintsByDate_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Red" BorderWidth="0px" />
             <EmptyDataTemplate>
               No Data Found for this Input. Try Again.
             </EmptyDataTemplate> 
             <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selected-row"  ForeColor="white" />
           </asp:GridView>
           <br />
        </asp:Panel>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there a bool in your database?

Comment: IMHO, I would define each column in the grid and bind each field for each row.  For the bool field, check it's value and set the checkbox accordingly.